# Basic number theory proofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> 1. Deduce that there is a prime gap of length $\geq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
> 2. Show that if $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.
> 3. Show that if $n$ is prime, then $2^n - 1$ is not divisible by $7$ for any $n > 3$.

1. I'm not really sure how to do the first bit.
2. For the second one, I'm not sure if this is correct but I have this: If $n$ is not prime, then $n = a b, a, b > 1$. Also $2^n - 1 = (2 - 1)(1 + 2 + 2^2 + .... + 2^{n-1})$. So if we substitute for $n = ab$, we get $(2^a)^b - 1 = (2^a - 1)(1 + 2^a + (2^a)^2 + .... + (2^a)^{b - 1})$ which is now composite and so if $n = ab$, then $2^n - 1$. This means that $2^n - 1$ is prime if $n$ is prime.
3. For the last one, we have a hint "Follow the example in lectures to show that $2^n - 1$ is not divisible by $3$", but I missed this lecture and haven't had a chance to get the note, so can someone help me with the divisible by $3$ bit and then I can try the divisible by $7$ bit myself.

Thank you

EDIT: I found a simpler proof for the second bit online:

> Supposed $n$ is composite, it can be then written in the form $n = ab, a, b > 1 \implies (2^a)^b - 1$ is prime with $b>1$ and $2^a>2$, contradicting statement $1$.

What is statement $1$? Maybe then I can understand why it contradicts it.

Comment: For the edit, it will be on the page you found.

Comment: Please show a bit more effort on your side to solve the homework problems.

Comment: Deduce from what? Previous exercises? Theorems given in class? From the statement "*For every $k$ there is a prime gap of at least $2^k$*"? The last one seems unlikely, though. Context and details are always good!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ohh, I didn't think about it like that! In the first two parts of that question, I already showed that every prime gap is even and that $n! + i$ for $1 < i < n$ is not a prime number.

Comment: Kaish, that's important and very useful information to the question which makes the first question much easier to answer -- even without having extensive knowledge in number theory.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains multiple, unrelated problems, and hence is unlikely to be of value to future readers.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I disagree that that means it is off-topic, or that that is a valid reason for closing. At the time, perhaps, but not 9 months later!

Comment: @user1729 I don't see the added value of a gathering of three questions, at least two of which have been posted individually already. After nine months, arguably the *only* relevance of a question is its value to future readers. Which, in this case, I argue to be negligible. Also, "off-topic" is only an artefact from the new closing scheme. I'd rather have voted "too localised".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have shown that there are no primes between $n!$ and $n!+n$, now it's time to combine this with the infinitude of prime numbers and we have the following:

**Claim:** Let $n>2$ be a natural number, let $p$ be the maximal prime number such that $p<n!$ and let $q$ be the least prime number such that $n!<q$, then there is no prime number between $p$ and $q$ and $q-p\geq n$.

*Proof.* The first part of the claim is true because any number between $p$ and $q$ would either be between $p$ and $n!$ in contradiction to how we chose $p$, or between $n!$ and $q$ which is a contradiction to how we chose $q$. The second part follows from the fact that $n!+i$ is not a prime number for any $i<n$ and therefore $p<n!+i<q$ and so $q-p\geq n$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you can use the idea of a factorial. Since you are looking for, say $n$ gap, start with $n!+2$. Then $n!+2$ can be divided by 2, since $n!=n(n-1)...2.1$ . Also $n!+k$ if $k$ is less than $n$ divides by $k$, and obviously $n!+n$ divides by $n$. That's a gap of $(n-1)$. If you want $n$ gap, start with (n+1)!.

Comment: So how does that being able to divide by $k$ show that there is a prime gap of length $n$?

Comment: @Kaish Have you given any thought to any strategies for showing that a number is not prime?

Comment: @ErickWong Yeah. Square root it and then see if you can divide by any of the prime numbers less that the square root. If you can't, then that number is prime.

Comment: @Kaish Note that I asked how to show a number is *not* prime.  What is the minimum evidence needed to show that $n!+k$ is not prime?

Comment: all n numbers in the sequence (n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,...,(n+1)!+(n+1) divide by the numbers 2,3,4,...,k,...,n, n+1 which means they are not primes.

Comment: @ErickWong Yeah, so that means if you can divide by a number less than the square root then it is not prime. The minimum ecidence needed would be to show that $n! + k$ can be divided by $k$?

Comment: @ciceksiz kakrot I still don't get how that shows the gap is $n$. Does it not just show that those numbers aren't prime?

Comment: @Kaish In that case, I must ask you what you think a prime gap is.  (It's important that the question says $\ge n$: if the gap had to be exactly $n$ then this would essentially be an unsolved problem.)

Comment: @ErickWong That gap between two prime numbers is the prime gap? So if $p < q$ where two prime numbers, then there prime gap would be $p - q$.

Comment: @Kaish What about the numbers in between $p$ and $q$?  Are any of those prime?

Comment: @ErickWong No, because $p$ and $q$ are consectutive primes. So the $n! + k$ bit shows that these numbers between $p$ and $q$ are not prime?

Comment: @Kaish Yes, the point is that if you find a lot of non-primes in a row, there must be a large prime gap somewhere surrounding them.  The essence of finding gaps is not about finding primes, but just the opposite.  It's a really simple connection when you think about it enough.

Answer (score 2):

For the second, you start with "Assume $n$ is not prime, (in which case you want to consider separately the case $n = 1$ which is not prime, and the case $n$ is composite"), so...(there exist $a>1$, $b>1$ such that $n = ab$).

Then you want to end with "hence, if $n = ab$, then $2^n - 1$ cannot be prime. So you've proven the contrapositive of the proposition, and should end with confirming the proposition: "if $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ must be prime."

Regarding your edit, I am assuming the statement 1 was an assumption, for the sake of contradiction, $n$ is not prime. So $n = 1$ or $n = ab, a, b>1$, and showing case 1: if $n = 1$, then $2^n - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$, which is not prime. Then what you see is "case 2"... and conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For the second part, argue by contrapositive as amWhy suggested. Suppose that $n = ab$. Show that $2^n - 1 = 2^{ab} - 1$ is composite by considering the difference of powers factorization
$$x^k - y^k = (x-y)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}y + \cdots + xy^{k-2} + y^{k-1})$$
It'll also be instructive to reason out why the method fails for prime exponent.

For the third part, consider 
$$2^n - 1 \pmod 7$$
As $n$ ranges through the natural numbers, the congruence repeats in a very obvious pattern. Try to reason out exactly when $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 1):

For the 3rd part, if $7\mid(2^n-1)$ where  $n$ is any natural number,

We get $2^n\equiv1\pmod 7$

Now, $2\equiv2\pmod 7,2^2\equiv4,2^3=8\equiv1\pmod 7\implies ord_72=3$

Form [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213361/showing-mathrmord-da-mid-mathrmord-ma-if-d-mid-m/213456#213456),  $ord_72\mid n\implies 3\mid n$

Now if $n$ is prime, $n$ must be $3$ else $n$ will be composite.